# Need help getting variable from URL

Tags: php

This is the code i use to set the variable in the URL:

```
<a href="topics.php?category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" class="list-group-item <?php echo is_active($category['id']); ?>"><?php echo $category['name'] ?> </a>
```

This is the code i use to get it from the URL:

```
<?php $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null;?>
```

And after that this is where i use it:

```
<?php if(isset($category)) : ?>
<?php foreach(getByCategory($category) as $post) : ?>
```

Where `getByCategory` is:

```
function getByCategory($category_id)
{
$db = new Database();

$category_id =("SELECT topic.*, categoryf.*, user.username, user.avatar 
            FROM topic, categoryf, user
            WHERE topic.category_id=categoryf.id AND
            topic.user_id=user.id");
$row =$db->select($category_id);

return $row;
}
```

What is the reason why the variable `$category` wont take the value from the URL?

Edit: This is what i get from `echo $category_id;`

```
SELECT topic.*, categoryf.*, user.username, user.avatar 
FROM topic, categoryf, user 
WHERE topic.category_id=categoryf.id 
AND topic.user_id=user.id
```

What i need here is to set $category_id as the variable in the URL, so i'd   like it to look like this:

```
SELECT topic.*, categoryf.*, user.username, user.avatar 
FROM topic, categoryf, user 
WHERE topic.1(category_id)=categoryf.id 
AND topic.user_id=user.id
```

Comment: Try a simple `echo $_GET['category'];` as soon as you have done the "GET"  then work forward from there - what does it say?   Try old-fashioned <?php if($_GET['category']){  $category = $_GET['category']; }else{ $category = null;} ?> for starters.

Comment: It shows the value as expected, i need to get id 1, it shows 1. Now what should i do? Should i use $this as an argument instead of $category_id?

Comment: work down the script - `echo $category;` and check its values.

Comment: Whatever you want with it? Did you try ```echo $category``` after your ternary if to verify the value is set to the $category variable correctly?

Comment: $category variable is correct, shows the expected value

Comment: echo $category_id; inside the function to check there - if that is there then something might not be quite right with `$row =$db->select($category_id);` You seem to be passing `$category` to `$category_id` in the function then overwriting it with the query

Comment: I posted the result as an edit

Comment: `WHERE topic.$category_id=categoryf.id ` no good? You also need to rename the variable you are holding the query in - eg `$category_id_query `and put that into the `select(...`

Comment: Tried, this is what i get `Unknown column 'topic.1' in 'where clause'35`

Comment: I fixed it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fixed it. For some reason it just couldn't get the value set, so i added `AND category_id=$category_id` to try and set it, and to my surprise it worked.

Comment: Magic give yourself the tick for answered question. Well done.